# How to get the averages of a hierarchical nested list structure?

Tags: python

I should compute the average of it using hierarchy, for example, in the sublist `[8,[9,91],11]` , I should first compute the average of `[9,91]`, and then the average of `[8,average of [9,91], 11]` and then the total average: `[2,average of [3,5], average of ([8,average of [9,91], 11])` etc....

I've been visualizing the code using http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use simple recursion:

```
def ave(d):
  return sum(ave(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in d)/float(len(d))

data = [2,[3,5],[6,6,7],[8,[9,91],11],[12,121,[[14]]]]
print(ave(data))
```

Output:

```
16.866666666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework, but you could give this a go. I do not know what the answer should be, but I came up with this:

```
def average_of(l):
    return sum(
        [(
            e if type(e) is int else average_of(e)
        ) for e in l if type(e)]
    ) / len(l)

a = [2, [3, 5], [6, 6, 7], [8, [9, 91], 11], [12, 121, [[14]]]]

print(average_of(a))
```

It prints

```
16.866666666666667
```

Edit: Ajax and I seemed to have posted the same answer at the same time.